# Javascript global variables and properties in nodejs - global properties sometimes deleted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

Why does the following print "undefined" when run in node (0.10.36)?

```
test = 'a global property';
var test = 'a variable';
console.log(global.test);
```

If the variable declaration is omitted (remove line 2), 'a global property' is logged as expected.

If the global property is set explicitly on the global object via `global.test = 'a global property'`, then it is also logged as expected.  I thought that these two statements were equivalent:

```
test = 'foo';
global.test = 'foo';
```

It almost seems like there is some situation where a variable declaration with the same name as an implicitly created global property causes that property to be deleted?

(I understand use of globals is generally bad practice, I am trying to understand how nodejs differs from various browsers in its handling of code relating to global property and variable declaration).

Comment: If you're working in the global scope, `test` and `var test `are equivalent.

Comment: @Aweary: This is nodejs. You're never in the global scope. If you use `var`, the variable will be accessible only in this file; otherwise it will be accessible from any file. This is an important distinction, since truly global variables are strongly discouraged.

Comment: It's an important distinction, good callout. I used the term global to contrast it with the local scopes of the functions within the current Node environment, but you're right, it's not truly global like you'd find in other environments.

Comment: ...but you seem to have been right in saying that, in the node console, declared variables not inside function definitions are still global. Eg `var test = 'foo'; global.test;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, variable declarations apply throughout the file (or the innermost enclosing function definition, if any):

```
pi = 3.14159265359;   // refers to declared variable pi
var pi;
function myFn() {
    x = 1.618034;     // refers to declared variable x
    if (...) {
        while (...) {
            var x;    // declaration only happens once each time myFn is called
        }
    }
}
x = 2.7182818;        // refers to global variable x
```

So in your example, the first line sets the value of the declared variable `test`, even though syntactically it's before the declaration. But `global.test` refers to the global variable `test`, which has not been set.

Comment: Ah, hoisting strikes again!  So my original code is equivalent to

    `var test;`
    `test = 'a global property';`
    `test = 'a variable';`

meaning a global property is **never** set.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`var` does not automatically keep you out of the global scope. If you're working in Node in the global namespace (say, in the Node REPL, where I tested this) `var test` is still going to be globally scoped unless you're defining it within a function.

```
//assign global without var
> test = 'global variable'
'global variable'
//this is still global, so it re-writes the variable
> var test = 'still global'
undefined
> test
'still global'
//if we defined test in a local scope and return it, its different
> var returnVar = function(){ var test = 'local test'; return test }
undefined
//and the global test variable is still the same
> test
'still global'
> returnVar()
'local test'
>
```